# Cannot find page but is active in the admin panel. Staging and locally no issues

Tags: routing, deployment

I've recently deployed an extension to an already existing craft website. I always have a staging website where we can make sure everything is working as expected. Everything was. When I pushed the website to production we were able to find the added entries in the admin console, but when we went to the url of the entry I didn't seem to find it.

The build was done trough deployHQ. I checked trough ftp if all the files were on the production server. I've tried doing a completely new build but without any succes. This all seems really weird to me because the staging server and the local server are working perfectly.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Does this ring any bells? :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, you deployed template changes/additions and also added new content as entries. You confirmed the template changes are there and the entries are there but they 404 when you visit the entry URLs in the browser?

Comment: Exactly. I've also checked the _views folder to make sure the twig templates are there.